# Pyschools Topic 3 Q 9

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm new to programming and I was trying out this question on Pyschools.

Can anyone help me?

> Write a function that converts the time to 24hr format.
>   Examples

```
>>> time24hr('12:34am')
'0034hr'
>>> time24hr('12:15pm')
'1215hr'
```

This question is under conditionals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove the "am" or "pm" from the end and save it off somewhere
2. Split on the ":", so you have hours and minutes separate
3. If the time is "am", print the hour unless the hour is "12", in which case print "00"
4. Otherwise (if the time is "pm"), print the hour + 12 unless the hour is "12", in which case print "12"
5. Print the minutes

Comment: And maybe this  is the code of this answer https://gist.github.com/Verurteilt/5989487

Answer (score 0):

```
def time24hr(tstr):
    time_list = tstr[:-2].split(':')
    time_int = [int(x) for x in time_list]
    am_pm = tstr[-2:]
    hours = time_int[0]
    minutes = time_int[1]
    if am_pm == 'am':
        if hours < 12:
            hours = hours + 12          
            return "%02d%02dhr" % (hours,minutes)
        else:
            return "00%2dhr" % (minutes)        
    else:
        if hours < 12:
            hours = hours + 12
            return "%02d%02dhr" % (hours,minutes)
        else:
            return "%02d%02dhr" % (hours,minutes)
```

Comment: "Write a function that converts the time to 24hr format"  
>>> time24hr('12:34am')
'0034hr'
>>> time24hr('12:15pm')                                                                   '1215hr'

Answer (score 0):

```
def time24hr(tstr):
    newTime = ""
    if "am" in tstr:
        for i in tstr:
            if i not in ":am":
                newTime += i
        if "12" in newTime[:2]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("12", "00")
            return newTime + "hr"
        elif len(newTime) == 3:
            newTime = "0" + newTime + "hr"
            return newTime
    elif "pm" in tstr:
        for i in tstr:
            if i not in "pm":
                newTime += i
        if "10" in newTime[:2]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("10", "22")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "11" in newTime[:2]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("11", "23")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "12" in newTime[:2]:
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "1" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("1", "13")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "2" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("2", "14")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "3" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("3", "15")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "4" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("4", "16")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "5" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("5", "17")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "6" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("6", "18")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "7" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("7", "19")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "8" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("8", "20")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        elif "9" in newTime[:1]:
            newTime = newTime.replace("9", "21")
            newTime = newTime.replace(":", "")
        return newTime + "hr"
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments inline

```
def time24hr(s):
    c = s.split(':') # Split string to list ["hh", "mmAP"] AP is "am" or "pm"
    h = int(c[0]) # convert hours string to integer
    m = int(c[1][0:-2]) # remove "AP" from "mmAP" and convert to integer. This will handle "mAP" input correctly as well.
    h = h % 12 if s[-2:] != 'pm' else 12 if h == 12 else h + 12 # convert hours to 24hr format, handling edge cases.
    return "%02d%02dhr" % (h, m) # Print hours and minutes as %02d - two digits, potentially filling with zeroes
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me better. I improved this based on the accepted answer.

1. Instead of using a loop to convert the list to integers, I call the values from the actual list and declare the variable as int type. Simple!
2. I still see no reason to add hours + 12 when the time is am and less than 12 hours–12hr and 24hr time format have the same format for am time, an exception of 12 am. Therefore, I just return the initial values from the function for the morning, and when it is exactly 12, I return hours %12 to have 00 am.

```py
def time24hr(tstr):
    time_list = tstr[:-2].split(':')
    
    t_list_int = []
    for e in time_list:
        t_list_int.append(e)
   
    minutes = int(time_list[1])
    hours = int(time_list[0])
    am_pm = tstr[-2:]
    
    if am_pm == 'am':
        if hours == 12:
            return "%02d%02dhr" % (hours%12,minutes)
        elif hours <12:
            return "%02d%02dhr" %(hours, minutes)
    else:
        if hours == 12:
            return "%02d%02dhr" %(hours, minutes)
        elif hours <12:
            return "%02d%02dhr" %(hours+12, minutes)

print(time24hr('9:34pm'))
print(time24hr('12:00am'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def time24hr(tstr):
    time=tstr.replace(':','')
    if 'am' in time:
        tim=int(time.replace('am',''))
    elif 'pm' in time:
        tim=int(time.replace('pm',''))
    mini=tim%100
    hour=tim//100 
    if mini<10:
        mini='0'+str(mini)
    else:
        mini=str(mini)
    if 'am' in time:
        if hour<10:
            hour='0'+str(hour)
        elif hour==12:
            hour='0'+str(hour-12)
            time1=time.replace('am','')
            time1=str(hour)+str(mini)+'hr'
    elif 'pm' in time:
        if hour<12:
            hour=12+hour
        elif hour==12:
            hour=hour
    time1=time.replace('pm','')
    time1=str(hour)+str(mini)+'hr'
    return time1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def time24hr(tstr): 
  a = tstr
  b = int(a[:2])+12
  if a[-2:] =='am' and a[:2]=='12':
      return '\'00'+a[3:-2]+'hr\''
  elif a[-2:]=='pm' and a[:2]=='12':
      return '\'12'+a[3:-2]+'hr\''
  else:
      if a[-2:] =='pm':
          return  "\'"+str(b)+a[3:-2]+'hr\''
      else:
        return "'"+a[:2]+a[3:-2]+'hr\''

print time24hr('12:15pm')
# '1215hr'
print  time24hr('12:15pm')
print time24hr('12:34am')
# '0034hr'
print time24hr('08:34am')
# '0834hr'
print time24hr('08:34pm')
'2034hr'
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it works (but it isn't too pretty :'C):

```
def time24hr(tstr):
  a=list(tstr)
  if len(a)==6:
    a.insert(0,'0')
  if a[5]=='a' and a[0]=='1' and a[1]=='2':
    del a[2]
    del a[4:6]
    a.append('h')
    a.append('r')
    a[0]='0'
    a[1]='0'
    w=''.join(a)
    return w
  elif a[5]=='p':
    del a[2]
    del a[4:6]
    a.append('h')
    a.append('r')
    x=a[0]+a[1]
    print x
    y=int(x)
    print y
    if y<12:
      z=y+12
      g=str(z)
      a[0:2]=g
      w=''.join(a)
      return w
    else:
      w=''.join(a)
      return w
  else:
    del a[2]
    del a[4:6]
    a.append('h')
    a.append('r')
    w=''.join(a)
    return w
```